# Move <top-frame> <page-context> toolbar to bottom

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Sorry for asking this kind of question but I spent hours to figure out how to complete this simple task. How to move the **<top-frame> <page-context>** toolbar to bottom of the dev tool.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fix that worked for me, is to change the style of the toolbar in Chrome's Custom.css.
But this will not work in next version, because of Google's decision to remove User Stylesheets (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=318566).

```
.console-status-bar {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

How to change Custom.css: http://darcyclarke.me/design/skin-your-chrome-inspector/

Comment: I don't know why the heck this happened to me. I'm totally sure I didn't touch anything inside Chrome style settings : [. Anyway, thanks for your answer. I will try it when I'm free.